# Access denied - add from existing content type for full control user

Tags: content-type, access-denied, content-type-hub

A custom content type is published in content type hub and consumed by a site collection. While adding this content type to a document library we are getting access denied error for full control user.
However **Site collection admin is able to add the content type without any error.**


The content type publishing error logs list doesn't have any error logs and ULS logs also display the same Access denied error. The same content type is working properly in other site collections and full control user is able to add it without any errors.
Hope to get some answers here.Thanks.

Comment: Is the same user able to add any other custom content types on this affected site?

Comment: Yes. If we create a custom content type inside the site collection then there is no issue.

Comment: Does anyone has a solution for this issue? We are facing the same in our environment. I just found out that a particular content type cannot be added to the libraries. For me it looks like the content type is broken since it it working when creating a new site collection content type.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if you are publishing a Site Collection level content type, then it would be by design that only site collection admins (which is effectively equivalent to full control of the site collection) could do this. Any user with lesser permissions, would then be able to affect a change to the whole site collection, without neccessarily having explicit permissions to all sites contained within it.

Comment: But we are not modifying the content type. The point is to add the content type to a document library which should not throw access denied error for a user with full control permission.